# Replace just start of string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have 3 columns in my table:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++
+ ID + Name +   Cell   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1  +  FB + /moon/ta +
+  2  +  GO + /ta/ta   +
+  3  +  MO + /ta/mon  +
+  4  +  SS + /ta      +
+  4  +  SS + /ta/o/ta +
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++
```

I want to replace all "/ta" with "/rr" in cell that start of string, like:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++
+ ID + Name +   Cell   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1  +  FB + /moon/ta +
+  2  +  GO + /rr/ta   +
+  3  +  MO + /rr/mon  +
+  4  +  SS + /rr      +
+  4  +  SS + /rr/o/ta +
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
update table t
    set cell = concat('/rr', substr(cell, 4))
    where cell like '/ta%';
```